# Proper nested array to JSON formatting for API curl post

Tags: php, json, curl

I am having trouble constructing a nested array properly to encode with JSON to post to an API.  I think my code array structure looks good, but I must have an error as only the auth, order_number, shipping variables post.  The order_items, variation_list, print_locations nested arrays do not post.  I'm thinking I must be missing an extra set of array () for the nested array definitions.  I tried a few variations, but none of my trial/error has worked.  Unfortunately, I do not receive an error back from the API with my following code.

How am I formatting this array incorrectly?  Any help is much appreciated.

My code:

```
$data = array(
    'auth'=>"$auth_key",
    'order_number'=>"$order_number",
    'shipping'=> array (
            'first_name'=>"John",
            'last_name'=>"Doe",
            'address1'=>"123 Someplace St.",
            'address2'=>"Apt or Suite",
            'city'=>"Town",
            'state'=>"PA",
            'postal_code'=>"16125",
        'country'=>"US"
    ),
    'order_items'=> array (
            'name'=>"Dale Blaney 2016 Design",
            'quantity'=>"1",
            'code'=>"1081389-GSS-FB-2XL-BK",
            'variation_list'=> array (
                    'size'=>"2XL",
                    'color'=>"Black", 
                    'style'=>"5000"
        ),
            'print_locations'=> array (
                    'location_name'=>"Full Front",
                    'location_art'=>"http://somedomain.com/link_to_your_artwork.png",
                    'location_preview'=>"http://somedomain.com/link_to_your_preview.png"
        )
    )


);

$data = json_encode($data);

$url = "https://blah.com/api/process14504.asp";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$TS_Result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo "$TS_Result";
```

Example JSON structure I was given:

```
{     "auth": "blahblahblah",      
     "order_number": 136794,
    "shipping": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "address1": "123 Someplace St.",
        "address2": "Apt or Suite",
        "city": "Town",
        "state": "PA", 
        "postal_code": "16125",
        "country": "US"
},
"order_items": [{
    "name": "Dale Blaney 2016 Design",
    "quantity": 1, 
    "code": "1081389-GSS-FB-2XL-BK",
    "variation_list": {
            "size": "2XL",
            "color": "Black",
            "style": "5000"
        },
        "print_locations": [{
            "location_name": "Full Front",
            "location_art": "http://somedomain.com/link_to_your_artwork.png", 
            }, 
       {"location_preview": "http://somedomain.com/link_to_your_preview.png"
            "location_name": "Full Back",
            "location_art": " http://somedomain.com/link_to_your_artwork.png",
            "location_preview": "http://somedomain.com/link_to_your_preview.png"
}] }] 
}
```

Comment: This JSON can't be from the provided PHP. `"location_name": "Full Back"` isn't in the PHP sample. Could you check your code please?

Comment: This wasn't required, so I left it out of the PHP.

Comment: I misunderstood that. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements that show brackets should be arrays of arrays, which makes sense given that "order_items" and "print_locations" can have multiple entries. You will need to nest the arrays a little deeper at those levels, like this:

```
'order_items'=> array (
    array( // one order item
        'name'=>"Dale Blaney 2016 Design",
        'quantity'=>"1",
        'code'=>"1081389-GSS-FB-2XL-BK",
        'variation_list'=> array (
            'size'=>"2XL",
            'color'=>"Black", 
            'style'=>"5000"
        ),
        'print_locations'=> array (
            array( // one print location
                'location_name'=>"Full Front",
                'location_art'=>"http://somedomain.com/link_to_your_artwork.png",
                'location_preview'=>"http://somedomain.com/link_to_your_preview.png"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

When you get to the actual implementation you will likely need to use some kind of loop on these fields to insert all the "order_items" and "print_locations"

Comment: Hi.  This is the correct answer.  Thank you so much for the help.  I have not worked with nested arrays so much.  Now I need to research the best way to build the arrays with a loop when dealing with multiple products.  1 step at a time.  Thank you so much.